# Is possible to retrieve the physical (device) camera height over the physical floor?

Tags: android, arcore

I'm developing an app using **ARCore**. In this app I need:

1) to place an object always staying at the same pose in world space. Following the "Working with Anchors" article recommendations (https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/developer-guides/anchors) I'm attaching an anchor to the **ARCore Session**. That is, I'm not using Trackables at all.

2) as a secondary requisite the object must be placed automatically, that is, without tapping on the screen.

I've managed to solve the two requisites, having now the object "floating" in front of me, this way (very common code):

```
private void onSceneUpdate(FrameTime frameTime) {
    ...
    if (_renderable!=null && _anchorNode==null) {            
        float[] position = {0f,0f,-10f};
        float[] rotation = {0,0,0,1};
        //
        Anchor anchor=_arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession().createAnchor(new Pose(position,rotation));
        //
        _anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
        _anchorNode.setRenderable(_renderable);
        _anchorNode.setParent(_arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
        _anchorNode.setLocalScale(new Vector3(0.01f,0.01f,0.01f)); //cm -> m
    ...
}
```

As i want the object to be on the floor, I need to find out what the height of my physical (device) camera above the floor is, in order to subtract that number from the current object's Y coordinate:

```
float[] position = {0f,HERE_THE_VALUE_TO_SUBTRACT_FROM_CAMERA_HEIGHT,-10f};
```

Certainly, it's an easy implementation when plane Trackables are used but here I have the requisites above-named.

I've managed to solve the two requisites, having now the object "floating" in front of me.

As i want the object to be on the floor, I need to find out what the height of my physical (device) camera above the floor is, in order to subtract that number from the current object's Y coordinate.

Trying with different camera/device **Pose** retrieval APIs, namely: **frame.getAndroidSensorPose()**, **frame.getCamera().getPose()** and **frame.getCamera().getDisplayOrientedPose()** are showing not valid values.

Thanks for your advice.

*P.S.:Certainly, it's an easy implementation when plane Trackables are used but here I have other requisites, as above-named.*

---

### EDIT after Michael Dougan comments.

Well I think we have then two ways to achieve the requisites:

1) leave the code w/o changes, keeping on using the **Session Anchor**, asking the user to launch the app and the to follow a "calibration process" which the device on the floor. As this is a professional use app, and not a consumer one, we think it is perfectly suitable;

2) go ahead with the good-and-old **Trackables**, by means of the usual floor as an anchor, including the pose of that anchor in the calculation of the position of the 3D model.

Comment: Any sort of sensor elevation is going to be height above sea level.  The only thing I can think of is that you have the user calibrate "floor" at the start of a session, saying, hold the phone next to the floor and press this button.  Then, save that elevation and subtract it from any other camera elevation readings to see how high the camera is off the floor.

Comment: Hi Michael, and thank you very much for your time.